# How can I make UI Text Field look like this in xcode 6?

Tags: iphone, ios7, uitextfield

This is the requirement

[image]

This is what I've been able to do

[image]

It seems the first pic is using only one field, but how can that be?

Comment: Are these `UIButton`s or `UITextField`s ?

Comment: yeah, sorry for the typo. Its a text field

Comment: You simply add the two `UITextField`s in a `UIView`. Set the `cornerRadius` and `backgroundColor` of the `UIView`. Lastly add a `CALayer` with 1px or 2px height in the middle to act as the separator.

Comment: @UtkarshSingh that comment should be an answer ;-)

Comment: Oh sorry, the comment of Utkarsh Singh will do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add your `UITextField`s in a `UIView` with `backgroundColor` `[UIColor whiteColor]`.
Also add a UIView with `UIView` with `backgroundColor` `[UIColor grayColor]` and height 1.0 px and width as your wish in between the two `UITextField`s.(This will act like the line seperator)
Now send the outer `UIView` to the function given below.

```
+(void)setCurvedEdges:(UIView*)view
{
    [view.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
    [view setClipsToBounds:YES];
}
```

Hope this will help you to achieve your goal.